# React Native fetch request to Microsoft Azure failing

Tags: reactjs, azure, http, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Azure OCR API found [here](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc) for a React Native app.

I can get the API to work fine on local images with Postman, but for some reason, I get an "Unsupported Media Type" when I try using `fetch` within my app.

I originally called the api with this code:

```
_analyzeImage = () => {
    const { image } = this.state;
    const url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr';
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append(image);
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '***********************',
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    });
}
```

Where `image` looks like:

[image]

That, when ran using the XCode simulator, yields:

[image]

And the response:

```
{
  "code":"UnsupportedMediaType",
  "requestId":"6ff43374-e5f9-4992-9657-82ec1e95b238",
  "message": "Supported media types: application/octet-stream, multipart/form-data or application/json"
}
```

Weirdly, the `content-type` seemed to be `test/plain`. So, even though I thought that the FormData object was supposed to take care of content type, I tried adding `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`, but got the same response (although the `content-type` header in the network inspector did change to `multipart/form-data`.

I used `create-react-native-app` to set up the project, and want to to work on iOS and android. If anyone has any ideas - or any other ways to do OCR, if there's a better native solution - I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You sure it takes form data and not octet stream?

Comment: Also your request payload doesn't look right. Should be all binary mumbo-jumbo not object object.

Comment: It can take either form data or octet stream, see [here](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc). What should the payload be? Right now, "image" in my function is the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [doc page you link to](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc), if you send

**application/json**, your payload must look like this:

```
{"url": "http://example.com/images/test.jpg"}
```

if **application/octet-stream**,

```
[Binary image data]
```

if **multipart/form-data**,

```
[Binary image data]
```

Right now you're not sending anything that matches expectations.

### Example POST

The image,

[image: hello]

Pass image by URL:

```bash
$ curl -v -X POST -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 2exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
                  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
                  --data-ascii '{ "url": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM7B3.png" }' \
                  https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr

> POST /vision/v1.0/ocr HTTP/1.1
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 44
...

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 196
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "language": "en",
  ...
  "regions": [
    {
    ...
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "61,49,303,108",
              "text": "hello."
            }
    ...
```

or pass image by raw bytes:

```bash
$ curl -v -X POST -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 2exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
                  -H 'Content-type: application/octet-stream' \
                  --data-binary @hello.png \
                  https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr

> POST /vision/v1.0/ocr HTTP/1.1
> Content-type: application/octet-stream
> Content-Length: 11623
...

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 196
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "language": "en",
  ...
  "regions": [
    {
    ...
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "61,49,303,108",
              "text": "hello."
            }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought `multipart/form-data` was done like [this](https://snowball.digital/Blog/Uploading-Images-in-React-Native). What do they mean by `[Binary image data]` - do I have to convert the image into base64 encoding?

Comment: This should work for form-data: `data.append('image', blob, 'image.jpg');`, but you need to upload the raw image bytes. If you're just sending it the URL to the image, you need to send `application/json`.