# How to convert a file-path URI to a readable https URL

Tags: javascript, azure, https, filepath

Is there a way to convert a captured file path uri as such 
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E1E919E-6C21-4CC7-B9C2-5B4B3BC84B0F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540chuks93%252Fihu-main/Camera/F3B8EBCC-BB09-4603-AF7E-FD3CA792C237.jpg` to say a temporary https URL?
Im working with the Microsoft azure face API and I'm running into errors that suggest that only way to run the API is with network URLs like `https`.

Anyone know of a workaround solution for this?

```
export default  {

processImage: (image) => {
// Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
var subscriptionKey = "********************";



var uriBase = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

// Display the image.
    var sourceImageUrl = image;
console.log(typeof sourceImageUrl)
console.log("here", sourceImageUrl);

// Perform the REST API call.
return fetch(uriBase, {

        method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({ uri: sourceImageUrl })
    })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then(function (data){
        console.log("hello", data);
    })


    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

}

Comment: I believe you got that wrong. You need to call Face API over HTTPS and upload the image blob in a POST request as [application/octet-stream](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236).

Comment: ok so is there a way i could use a photo taken by react-native camera and pass it into the API and it would work? Perhaps as you said call it over a HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's just a POST request - see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936909/react-native-fetch-request-to-microsoft-azure-failing/

Comment: so above I added my code. when i take a photo with the react-native camera it returns a file uri "file://" but the API only seems to function with files that start with "https://".